# Can I make my website read text to users with assistive technologies (VoiceOver/JAWS), only?

Tags: web-applications, accessibility, wai-aria

I would like to provide a bit of assistance to blind users by having my website read something to them, briefly. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can provide content that will be read to users using a screen reader (but not shown to sighted users) is by positioning the content using CSS such that it is offscreen.

E.g. Something like:

In CSS:

```
.screen-reader { 
  position: absolute; 
  left: -10000px; 
  width: 1px; 
  height: 1px; 
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

In your HTML:

```
<p>This text will be read to the screen reader and shown on screen.</p>
<p class="screen-reader">This text will be read to a screen reader but won't show up on screen.</p>
```

See [Techniques for hiding text](http://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/#techniques) (at WebAIM) for more info.

Comment: You can use it to provide indicators to a blind user about things that are clear to a sighted user.  See http://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/#cues for couple examples.

Comment: I got you.  I misinterpreted this question.  Didn't realize he was only talking about giving some info to the blind user opposed to actually coding an accessible website!

Comment: @Chris Buckler "skip to main content" links are designed for a lot more people than only blind. Citing WCAG 2.0 G1 Technique `Visible links are necessary for those navigating with a keyboard including switch users, those using techniques that generate keyboard strokes slowly, screen magnification software users, screen reader users working with sighted colleagues, keyboard only users and those navigating using voice recognition software.` http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/G1.html In fact blind users can navigate by headings, links and even ARIA landmark regions w/ very recent JAWS/NVDA readers

Comment: @Felipe I am well aware of that. Wrote the guidelines based off the WCAG 2.0 and WEBAIM techniques... Not sure why you are directing this towards me hah, A little more on that, you are only required to implement the skip to main content, when other frames or content blocks such as navigation, or horizontal menu bar are present.

Comment: @Felipe Alsacreations Keep a few things in mind when creating a skip to main link. You always want to be sure that the skip link moves keyboard focus as well as visual focus.  You can do this by adding a tabindex of -1 to your anchor.  Before any of you start to flare about the -1 value, I am well aware that this is an invalid value, but it is the current workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This is a web-technology in progress. One I know of is Google Text-To-Speech, but it requires Html 5 to play without clicking/download. Ref: http://weston.ruter.net/projects/google-tts/